# SQL Database normalization and data insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server

№1 source table: sales (from unstructured file .csv)

| id | auto | gasoline_consumption | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lada Vesta, grey | 7.3 | Russia |
| 2 | BMW F80, red | 8.3 | Germany |
| 3 | Hyundai Elantra, red | 5 | South Korea |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

```
CREATE TABLE [sales](
    [id] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [auto] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [gasoline_consumption] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [country] [nvarchar] (50)

) ON [PRIMARY];

INSERT INTO sales values(1,'Lada Vesta, grey', 7.3, 'Russia');
INSERT INTO sales values(2,'BMW F80, red', 8.3, 'Germany');
INSERT INTO sales values(3,'Hyundai Elantra, red', 5, 'South Korea');
```

№2 source table: Brand

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Lada |
| 2 | Hyundai |
| 3 | BMW |
| ... | ... |

```
CREATE TABLE Brand (
id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(50),
);

INSERT INTO Brand values(1, 'Lada');
INSERT INTO Brand values(2,'Hyundai');
INSERT INTO Brand values(3,'BMW');
```

№3 source table: Color

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | grey |
| 2 | red |
| ... | ... |

```
CREATE TABLE Color (
id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(15)
)

INSERT INTO Color values(1, 'grey');
INSERT INTO Color values(2,'red');
```

№4 source table: Country

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Russia |
| 2 | Germany |
| 3 | South Korea |
| ... | ... |

```
CREATE TABLE Country (
id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO Country values(1, 'Russia');
INSERT INTO Country values(2,'Germany');
INSERT INTO Country values(2,'South Korea');
```

№5 Example of the final table: Cars

| id | id_brand | model_name | gasoline_consumption | id_color | id_country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | F80 | 8,3 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | Vesta | 7,3 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | Elantra | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

```
CREATE TABLE Cars (
id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
id_brand INT NOT NULL,
model_name varchar (30),
gasoline_consumption DECIMAL(3,1),
id_color INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (id_brand) REFERENCES Brand (id),
FOREIGN KEY (id_color) REFERENCES Color (id),
FOREIGN KEY (id_country) REFERENCES Country (id)
)
```

[image]

I was able to transfer colors, car brand and country from the original table to other tables. But now I don't understand how to enter data into the "Cars" table if need to take into account the id relationship between the car brand, country, color and model name.

***Note: These data are given as an example, in fact there are about 1000 of them there***

Comment: so how doy you manage to split the source table into the many sub tables, whey you extract grey you know the id and can enter them into cars, the same goes for the other ids. i would write a procedure to parse the columns and use it to finally get the cars table

Comment: @nbk The fact is that from the file .csv is about 1000 rows and I inserted them using SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX and now I don't quite understand how to insert data into the Cars table.

The original task was to bring the data into the third normal form, but maybe I'm doing it completely wrong...

Comment: please show your code how you parse it, and as i said write a procedure that looks if for example grey exsists, if not insert it get the new id and save it in a variable, then you proceed for all other tables the same way, thus you can go from row to row and generate the cars table and insert the data into the sub tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join back to your reference tables to get back the id, e.g.

```
INSERT dbo.Cars (id_brand, model_name, gasoline_consumption, id_color, id_country)
SELECT  id_brand = b.id,
        model_name = SUBSTRING(s.auto, CHARINDEX(' ', s.auto), CHARINDEX(', ', s.auto) -CHARINDEX(' ', s.auto)),
        gasoline_consumption = TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(3, 1), s.gasoline_consumption),
        id_color = cr.id,
        id_country = c.id
FROM    dbo.Sales AS s
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Country AS c 
            ON c.name = s.country
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Brand AS b 
            ON b.name = LEFT(s.auto,CHARINDEX(' ', s.auto))
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Color AS cr 
            ON cr.name = TRIM(RIGHT(s.auto, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(s.auto))))
```

*N.B. The above is inaccurate and won't work many values in `auto. If you have a colour such as "Sky Blue" it will fail, if you have a brand like "Land Rover", it will fail. The parsing logic shown is simple and for demo purposes, this should be replaced with your actual parsing logic.*

You should probably encapsulate your parsing logic though to avoid repeating yourself and reduce code maintenance, something like:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Sales_Parsed
AS
SELECT   model_name = SUBSTRING(s.auto, CHARINDEX(' ', s.auto), CHARINDEX(', ', s.auto) -CHARINDEX(' ', s.auto)),
            gasoline_consumption = TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(3, 1), s.gasoline_consumption),
            color = TRIM(RIGHT(s.auto, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(s.auto)))),
            brand = LEFT(s.auto,CHARINDEX(' ', s.auto))
FROM    dbo.Sales AS s;
```

You can then reference this view when populating your reference tables, e.g.

```
INSERT dbo.Country (name)
SELECT DISTINCT sp.Country
FROM   dbo.Sales_Parsed AS sp
EXCEPT
SELECT  c.name
FROM    dbo.Country AS c;

INSERT dbo.Color (name)
SELECT DISTINCT sp.color
FROM   dbo.Sales_Parsed AS sp
EXCEPT
SELECT  c.name
FROM    dbo.color AS c;

INSERT dbo.Brand (name)
SELECT DISTINCT sp.brand
FROM   dbo.Sales_Parsed AS sp
EXCEPT
SELECT  c.name
FROM    dbo.Brand AS c;
```

And also where you populate your cars table:

```
INSERT dbo.Cars (id_brand, model_name, gasoline_consumption, id_color, id_country)
SELECT  id_brand = b.id,
        s.model_name,
        s.gasoline_consumption,
        id_color = cr.id,
        id_country = c.id
FROM    dbo.Sales_Parsed AS s
        INNER JOIN dbo.Country AS c 
            ON c.name = s.country
        INNER JOIN dbo.Brand AS b 
            ON b.name = s.brand
        INNER JOIN dbo.Color AS cr 
            ON cr.name = s.color;
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iEJaqLcj)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two different ways:

**1. way (manual):**

```sql
INSERT INTO 
   Cars (id_brand, model_name, gasoline_consumption, id_color, id_country)
VALUES
   (3, 'F80', 8.3, 2, 2),
   (1, 'Vesta', 7.3, 1, 1),
   (2, 'Elantra', 5, 2, 3)
```

**2. way (with SELECT):**
If you run a script or anything else you can use TSQL (if you are using SQL Server) to itterate over all single lines from your import table. Then you can extract your values which you inserted in all the other tables programatically from the columns and then you can use a SELECT to get the correct Id like in this very simple example:

```sql
INSERT INTO 
   Cars (id_brand, model_name, gasoline_consumption, id_color, id_country)
VALUES
   (SELECT 
       id 
    FROM
       Brand
    WHERE
       name = 'BMW',
    'F80',
    8.3, 
    SELECT
       id
    FROM
       Color
    WHERE 
       name = 'red',
    SELECT
       id
    FROM
       Country
    WHERE name = 'Germany'),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to what to enter for the foreign keys following very basic logic, then you need to know what the ID of the relevant value for the relevant table is.

So if you wanted to insert 'BMW' as car type, you would need to find the ID of that, which in this case would be 3.

The ID/Identity column will be auto populated when creating an entry (unless you have INSERT_IDENTITY set to ON.

When inserting values, if you use a column list to explicitly state what you are inserting values, it can help to clear up exactly what you are adding. You can insert entries in the following way b

```
-- Explicit
INSERT INTO Cars (
    id_brand,
    model_name, 
    gasoline_consumption, 
    id_color, 
    id_country
)
VALUES (3, 'F80', 8.3, 2, 2) 


-- Implicit 
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES (3, 'F80', 8.3, 2, 2)
```